# HTML5 Fake Fullscreen Video with VideoJS

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I'm trying to watch html5 video in fullscreen , without fullscreen request.

Something like that: http://pmkmedia.nl/uploads/demos/clicktestvideo5.html

This works but i am trying that with video.js because , i need to watch rtmp live stream..

Another question : how can i put video element without know video size ?

(i already tried put width="auto" and height="auto" but nothing changes.)

How can i solve that ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in that page if you view the contents.  Use css to specify width and height of 100% for the video.

```
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)